# Atmel XMEGA384C3 PWM

Tags: avr, atmel

I have a general question regarding the XMEGA384C3 [DataSheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8361-8-and-16-bit-AVR-XMEGA-Microcontrollers-ATxmega384C3_Datasheet.pdf). For PORTF, it has a timer 0. Then I can use PF0-PF3 for PWM. Is it possible to have individual PWM duty cycles for each channel simultaneously.

For example PF0 (0C0A) is outputting 50% duty cycle. While PF1 (0C0B) is outputting 75% duty cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer has 4 comparitors which means that each PWM output can have its own independent duty cycle however they must all have the same period.

Comment: Are you talking about the Counter Period or the PWM output period?

Comment: They are the same thing. The PWM output is low when the counter is greater than the compare register and high when it is less. This means that the PWM period must be the same as the counter period. See the manual section 13.8.3 for details http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8465-8-and-16-bit-AVR-Microcontrollers-XMEGA-C_Manual.pdf (For CPUs the datasheet tells you how to connect it up, the manual tells you how it works)